# Graphs/Charts in Latex

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

Being new to Latex, I'm finding it hard to draw graphs in latex.[image]

I wish to draw this graph. Can anyone please help me with the same?
Here is the code I had been trying to use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} 
\addplot coordinates { (1950,3) (1969,2.80) (1969,2.80) }; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And this is the data: (1950,3) (1969,2.80) (1978,2.796) (1979,2.78) (1981,2.548) (1982,2.517) (1984,2.496) (1986,2.479) (1989,2.367)
I want my graph to be almost the same as in the picture attached.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you help us help you with providing what you have tried so far, and the data for the graph?

Comment: One option is to draw the graph in the software of your choice, save the result in a PDF  or JPG file, and import the graph into LaTeX using the `\includegraphics` macro of the `graphicx` package.

Comment: If doing so, I strongly recommend using a vector format.  However, among the pixel based formats, you'd rather use PNG, because JPEG will have compression artifacts in pictures with high contrast, clear edges and thin lines.

Comment: @vaettchen : This is the code I'm trying to use.\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
(1950,3)
(1969,2.80)
(1969,2.80)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} But, I'm unable to get the text portion onto the graph (as in the picture above). I mean the labels.

Comment: Thanks @StevenB.Segletes ! But, if you could have a look at my code(previous comment) and help me with it, then that'll be great.

Comment: @vaettchen And of course, this is not the entire data as you can see from the figure. I was just testing if my code works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't do `tikz`, and cannot, therefore, help you in that regard.

Comment: I also recommend using `pgfplots`. The manual is comprehensive. The following [short presentation](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/Graphs.pdf) shows some of the possibilities.

Comment: @user82698 Editing the question to include the code,  and extending it to a complete document, would improve the question a lot. The code snippet is a bit hidden away in that comment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have edited the question. You can have a look at it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

UPDATED
Here is how it works, using your more complete data set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      width=\textwidth,
      height=.8\textwidth,
      axis lines=center,
      xmin=1950,
      xmax=1990,
      xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      ymin=2.35,
      ymax=3,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates { (1950,3) (1968,3) (1969,2.80) (1978,2.796) (1979,2.78) (1981,2.548) (1982,2.517) (1984,2.496) (1986,2.479) (1989,2.367)};
        \end{axis}
        \node at (3,7.8){naive};
        \node at (4,5.8){Strassen};
        \node at (6.8,6){Pan};
        \node at (8.5,5.5){Bini et al.};
        % etc.....

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could I change the scale on the x-axis and y-axis? Here's the data: (1950,3) (1969,2.80) (1978,2.796) (1979,2.78) (1981,2.548) (1982,2.517) (1984,2.496) (1986,2.479) (1989,2.376) . With the above code, I get a really cramped figure. The scale used in the picture attached to my original question, makes the graph look a bit neater. How could I do so?

Comment: @user82698 change `ymin=0` to `ymin=2.35`

Comment: @cfr I had read about that but forgot - changed now to article.